# Bash Scripting - Search files for line above search criteria

Tags: bash, grep, full-text-search

I have 100s of config files, each 10,000 to 20,000 lines long. These are config files for hardware.  I need to search through all the config files to find the "profile" associated with a given cert name. There are several different versions of hardware software so the configs files are somewhat different. However the profile name is always above the cert. The profile name does not necessarily contain the cert name.

Example of Profile Names:
    clientssl_www.profile-cert
    clientssl_www.example.com-cert

Example of Cert Name:
    www.example.com.crt

Example sections of config:

```
profile clientssl clientssl_www.profile-cert {
   defaults from clientssl
   key "www.example.com.key"
   cert "www.example.com.crt"
   chain "Intermediate-bundle.crt"
   options {
      cipher server preference
      dont insert empty fragments
      no sslv2
   }
}

ltm profile client-ssl /Common/clientssl_www.example.com-cert {
    app-service none
    cert /Common/www.example.com.crt
    cert-key-chain {
        www.example.com_www.example.com {
            cert /Common/www.example.com.crt
            chain /Common/Intermediate-bundle.crt
            key /Common/www.example.com.key
        }
    }
    chain /Common/Intermediate-bundle.crt
    ciphers 
    key /Common/www.example.com.key
    options { dont-insert-empty-fragments cipher-server-preference no-sslv2 }
}
```

I cannot read the config files line by line as there are millions of lines and it simply takes too long.
I can find the cert name with **grep** using something like this:

```
$ grep www.example.com *file.conf | egrep 'cert "|cert /Common'
```

Which gives me something like this:

```
   cert "www.example.com.crt"
    cert /Common/www.example.com.crt
            cert /Common/www.example.com.crt
```

I need to find the 'profile name' that is above my search for a given cert name.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for `-B` option of grep?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `-B` option of `grep` which comes handy in such cases. From the *man* pages for `grep`:

```
-B NUM, --before-context=NUM
      Print  NUM  lines of leading context before matching lines.  Places a line containing a group separator (--) between contiguous groups
      of matches.  With the -o or --only-matching option, this has no effect and a warning is given.
```

So, the pattern match will now be:

```
$ grep www.example.com *file.conf | egrep -B3 'cert "|cert /Common'
```

Output:

```
profile clientssl clientssl_www.profile-cert {
   defaults from clientssl
   key "www.example.com.key"
   cert "www.example.com.crt"
--

ltm profile client-ssl /Common/clientssl_www.example.com-cert {
    app-service none
    cert /Common/www.example.com.crt
    cert-key-chain {
        www.example.com_www.example.com {
            cert /Common/www.example.com.crt
```

However, you will still need to figure out some common pattern in the line containing `profile name` to single them out. It becomes difficult in your example to filter it further because in the first case,  the *profile name* is three lines before the `cert "` pattern whereas in the second example, it is two lines before `cert /` pattern.

Another approach which i find better is to find some pattern in the `profile name` itself. If all profile names contain the string `profile` or if they have a pattern such as `clientssl.*-cert`, then the following pattern match will do what you need:

```
$ grep www.example.com *file.conf | egrep 'profile|clientssl.*-cert'
```

Output:

```
profile clientssl clientssl_www.profile-cert {
ltm profile client-ssl /Common/clientssl_www.example.com-cert {
```

Even better, if you know that the *profile name* starts with clientssl_ and ends with -cert, then

```
$ grep www.example.com *file.conf | grep -o clientssl_.*-cert
```

Output:

```
clientssl_www.profile-cert
clientssl_www.example.com-cert
```

Comment: OK, so if I go 3 lines before my search criteria then grep for 'profile' which is always in the profile name line, then clean up the results...

`$ grep -B 3 www.example.com *file.conf | grep profile | sed 's/ {//' | sed 's/file.conf[-:]/file.conf /' | sed 's/\/Common\///' | awk {'print $1,$NF'}`

Output:
`test1.file.conf clientssl_www.profile-cert`
`test2.file.conf clientssl_www.example.com-cert`

There's probably some ways of simplfying my cleaning up of the kruft but the above seems to work if not pretty.

Comment: There was a reason I had opted not to use the -B flag with grep previously. I think it had something to do with the inconsistency of how many lines are between what I was searching for and the profile name line, however with my sample data it works nicely. I think my problem using grep -B is the profile line may be as little as 2 lines above or as many as 6-7 lines above. If I go 7 lines above I may get results for stuff that I don't want. I'll have to test it to see.

Comment: For your second comment, that's exactly the thing i mentioned in my answer because using `-B` option might help filter out few lines but it depends because even you aren't sure whether the _profile name_ is 3 or 4 or 5... lines above the _cert_ string. So the best way in this case would be to find some pattern in the line containing the _profile name_ string which i already suggested in my answer.

After going through your first comment, yes, there's definitely a better way and that i feel is `grep -o clientssl_.*-cert *file.conf`. This should do the trick.

Comment: I think we're on the same page. I opted to not use `grep -o clientssl_.*-cert` because that is the part of the config that is the NAME of the SSL profile and it could be anything, (lots of people with their fingers in the configs and nobody seems to use the same naming convention). I used `grep profile` as 'profile' is a reserved word and always specifies the profile, then I can filter with sed & awk for the name of the profile.

Answer (score 0):

This may be madness, but whenever I see sample data that fits Tcl's syntax rules, I look to produce a Tcl solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

proc unknown {cmdname args} {
    set data [lindex $args end]
    if {[set idx [lsearch -exact $data "cert"]] != -1 && [string match $::cert_pattern [lindex $data [incr idx]]]} {
        set idx [expr {$cmdname eq "profile" ? 1 : [lsearch -exact $args "profile"] + 2}]
        puts [lindex [split [lindex $args $idx] /] end]
    }
}

set cert_pattern "*[lindex $argv 0]*"
foreach file [lrange $argv 1 end] {
    source $file
}
```

Then

```
$ ./cert.tcl www.example.com file.conf 
file.conf
clientssl_www.profile-cert
clientssl_www.example.com-cert
```

I won't bother to explain how it works unless there's a hue and cry.